# Easy way to do mysql "INSERT INTO" to Mysqllite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database-migration, insert-into

Hi I have the following Mysql code (Which i export from Mysql DB before I delete my tables from it). Now I have a MySQLlite DB, and I have the corresponding tables in this database. But when I run the INSERT INTO command exported from MySQL database is not seems to be working in MySQLlite. When I research I see that I need to manually add each row as one single INSERT INTO command. I have 100 of rows. It's almost impossible to do that. Any Idea guys how to do this insertion? Thanks in advance..

MYSQL INSERT INTO Command:

```
INSERT INTO `DEPT` (`id`, `dept_name`, `bp_name`, `standard`, `created_by_id`, `modified_by_id`, `date_created`, `date_modified`) VALUES
(23,    'DEQP', 'Kaizen',   'IEC 60812',    286,    286,    '2016-05-16 14:32:30',  '2016-05-19 14:25:06'),
(31,    'DEQP', 'test', 'IEC 60812',    286,    286,    '2016-05-22 10:50:06',  '2016-05-22 10:55:55'),
(32,    'IT',   'Design',   'IEC 60812',    286,    286,    '2016-05-22 11:13:06',  '2016-05-22 11:13:06');
```

Comment: That syntax looks fine for SQLite. What happens when you run it?

Comment: Error as "Error in query: near ",": syntax error"

Comment: [Worked fine for me.](http://pastebin.com/JASLVAYr) Are you sure the command you're running is the same as the one in your question?

Comment: yes am sure duskwuff, using sqlite3

Comment: There is not database called "MySQLite".

Answer (score 1):

Export the data from table to a file using

```
  SELECT *
  INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM DEPT
```

And after exporting use the file to import data into your mysqlite server using

Load data local infile.....
Check this link [**MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Andrews, I have already exported the data from Mysql, and the tables are already deleted from the Mysql Database.

Comment: You have the query to insert 100 rows in mysql use the query to insert data into mysql and after that do the steps I've suggested

Comment: "use the query to insert data into mysql" that means I need to create the tables again in the database? Thats almost impossible also Andrews. Any other ways?

Comment: yes you have to create tables again.... :( thats the sad part @vellattukudy

Answer (score 0):

SQLite insert one row per line.

SQLite with PHP_PDO will allow you insert multiple rows in one insert. Have a try SIDU: http://topnew.net/sidu see if it can help you.